# How to set a specific flexbox gap in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid-layout

I'm trying to achieve a `flexbox` layout with just one `flex-grow` element and a variable number of smaller elements around it. I need a gap between the elements that's a fixed width - exactly one pixel. Here's a diagram of what I want:

[image]

The blue element grows to fill the space, but has a 1px gap in between every element.

How do I create this fixed width gap?

---

### Potential non-flexbox solution

I didn't know how to achieve that precise 1 pixel gap in `flexbox`, so I was trying to create it in a `grid` layout. I ran into a different issue of not having a `flex-grow` property for grid children:

```
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}
.big-element {
  // <- Need something similar to flex-grow for this element
}
```

Comment: `grid` and `flex` are two different things in CSS. It's advisable you research before asking on SO.

Comment: I know. I edited my question to clarify that my grid layout attempt in creating the gap is not related to flexbox.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The CSS spec has recently been [updated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap#Flex_layout) to apply `gap` properties to flexbox elements in addition to CSS grid elements. [This feature is supported on the latest versions of all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox-gap). With the `gap` property, you can get what you want just by adding a `column-gap: 1px` rule.

Comment: This is so cool, and such a timesaver!  It's a good time to be a web developer.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

You may use margin/padding to create this gap:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
  margin:10px 0;
  padding: 1px 0 1px 1px;
}

.e {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 1px;
  background: red;
}

.b {
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### TailwindCSS Solution

Tailwind comes with a built-in set of [gap](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap) classes that will add the specified gap to grid and flexbox items.

You can use gap-# to apply the gap to all sides of the items or gap-x-#/gap-y-# to apply the gap on just the horizontal or vertical sides.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

A quick hack add a solid bored the thickness of the required gap and set the colour to transparent eg
border: .75rem solid transparent;